# animating multiple textviews

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

whats the best way to accomplish the following,

I need to update these textivews from lets say 0 to 1000 simultaneously, but it has to seem like the textview is counting up. You know like a count down animation. Except it goes from a specific value to a higher value. I tried running multiple threads and updating the textviews but I don't think is a good approach, I also used a thread executor.

textview 1 - 0 - 100 | 
textview 2 - 0 - 300 |
textview 3 - 0 - 600 |
textview 4 - 0 - 100 |

Comment: ummm can you please be a little more elaborate ...? I couldn't understand the head and tails of it

Comment: @kishu27 better? does it make sense?

Comment: Are you still there? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the `Chronometer` class? It's a pretty basic class, extending `TextView`, that uses a simple `Handler` with `sendMessageDelayed` to update the value. See the method `updateRunning()` in the source.

Comment: yeah but i have multiple textviews...think of it like a graph with progressview and textviews next to each other and there say 10...

Comment: I don't understand why having multiple views would make a difference. You're going to have to explain what you're actually doing here if you hope to get a better answer. How is the range set? How are the values set? Please update question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thread you should try Handler,in handler's postDelayed method you can pass runnable to execute code to update your textview and again schedule handler for next postDelayed execution.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of my answer.